# need a special image slider with views

Tags: views, javascript

Is there any module that works with views and slide images like the following image?

[image]

so far I've found about 13 image slider in Drupal but non of them does such thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot is provided. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: No @Mołot this is the PSD of my a site I'm going to implement, that is why I'm looking for a module for it.

Comment: @Drupalist Don't forget, this is a **Q+A** site. It's not a support forum/suggestion engine. We specifically don't want this type of question here _because_ it's the PSD of your specific site. You're narrowing the scope so much that the question can only be useful to you, and not to future visitors, which goes against what the site is for. Please see the help center, where this type of question is specifically disallowed: _Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided_

Comment: Ok @Clive got it.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that by [jCarousel](https://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module

> This module allows developers and themers to make use of the jCarousel jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use, as well as Views integration in the 2.0 version so that you can turn any list of content or images into a carousel.

Comment: its Other releases download link background is yellow, are you sure there is no problem with it ?

Comment: I think so, I've used it one of my project and works well. Just see reported installs under project information.